# Retrieve specefic URL from string of multiple URLs

Tags: python, indexing, slice

I have a list of URLS in a string and I need to retrieve a specific URL from the string. (Using Python)

Here is the output string:

```
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=100&q=60 100w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=200&q=60 200w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=60 300w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60 400w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 500w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60 600w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60 700w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60 800w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60 900w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=60 1000w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=60 1100w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1200&q=60 1200w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1296&q=60 1296w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=60 1400w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=60 1600w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1800&q=60 1800w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=60 2000w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=60 2200w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2400&q=60 2400w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2588&q=60 2588w
```

I want to extract the URL that is before 1800w and after 1600w. Any help on how to go about this will be helpful!

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its always the part between 1600w and 1800w you can use this regex.

```
import re

regex = r"1600w,(.+)1800w"

test_str = "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=100&q=60 100w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=200&q=60 200w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=60 300w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60 400w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60 500w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60 600w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=60 700w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60 800w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60 900w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=60 1000w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=60 1100w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1200&q=60 1200w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1296&q=60 1296w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1400&q=60 1400w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=60 1600w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1800&q=60 1800w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2000&q=60 2000w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2200&q=60 2200w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2400&q=60 2400w, https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1535083783855-76ae62b2914e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2588&q=60 2588w"

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

print(matches[0])
```